# Best open-source symmetric-only file encryption utility apart from PGP?

Tags: security, encryption

I need to e-mail a file to someone with whom I have already negotiated a password.
What are reputable, reliable and open-source tool with simple UI? An example for disk (as opposed to file) encryption is TrueCrypt.
Platform is windows but available linux port is a plus.

Comment: Adam, once I see the good answer for my question I will up upvote it. So far I have not found a 'truecrypt for files' I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

[AxCrypt](http://www.axantum.com/axCrypt/) seems to be a good place to start from. Quoting its webpage:

> AxCrypt is the leading open source
>   file encryption software for Windows.
>   It integrates seamlessly with Windows
>   to compress, encrypt, decrypt, store,
>   send and work with individual files.

If you want to add some nice spice into it, and you're exchanging these files on a regular basis, create an encrypted disk within a file with [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) and share it with your friend using [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). It will give you a flexible, seamless directory structure which is automatically encrypted and synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [GNU Privacy Guard](http://www.gnupg.org/)?

Comment: It should be a sinple thing to use: click-dowloaded-click-installed-click-password and file to encrypt - done.

Comment: @99CPU there are actually several GUIs for GPG. All of them provide a very simple way of using GPG. E.g. http://www.gpg4win.org/

Answer (score 1):

[7-Zip](http://7-zip.org) encrypts files and is also the best open-source file archiver.

Answer (score -1):

EncryptPad is an application for viewing and editing symmetrically encrypted text. It also provides a tool for encrypting and decrypting binary files on disk. It works on Windows, Mac and Linux and supports OpenPGP file format.

[image]

Link - http://evpo.net/encryptpad/

I am the developer by the way.